# How to update Android project with Gradle?

Tags: android, gradle

I'm trying to update an Android project (cloned from googlesource.com)

`git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/AlarmClock`

from command line but `android update project --help` doesn't have option for gradle.

I can create a new project with gradle from this command:

`android create project -n AlarmClock -t 'android-22' -p ~/AlarmClock -k com.name.AlarmClock -a AlarmClock -g -v 0.10.0`

where `-g` is for Gradle template.

But how do I update?

I was previously using Ant but now with Gradle because Android developer site recommends it (http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-cmdline.html).

If there's no specific command to update, what options do I have to build existing project with gradle?

Comment: "If there's no specific command to update, what options do I have to build existing project with gradle?" -- put a `build.gradle` file in the project root, set up for the project. That specific app may still not be buildable, as most AOSP apps are not designed to be built individually, but only as part of a firmware build, and then only via the makefiles.

Comment: @CommonsWare I tried that but I got an error `Task 'build' not found in root project 'AlarmClock'`

Comment: Then presumably there are problems with your `build.gradle` file, such as missing the Gradle for Android plugin.

Comment: I can do `gradle init` command and it will create the `build.gradle` file but it will give me that error and will say `BUILD FAILED`. Not sure what step need to take.

Comment: I would suggest copying a `build.gradle` file from elsewhere, for a similar sort of project, and adjusting it as needed. Since AOSP apps should be fairly close to Eclipse-style projects, using a `build.gradle` for an Eclipse-style project, like [this one](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/master/Accessibility/FontScale/build.gradle), may help.